# Dockerizing Django application: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X"

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

I've been trying to follow this guide to Dockerize a project:

[Deploy and Run Django in Dokcer Container](https://dev.to/joekreydt/deploy-django-in-a-docker-container--41n6)

This is the base file structure:

```
WFMBCM
|-WFMBCM
| |-__init__.py
| |-__pycache__
| |-setting.py
| |-url.py
| |-wsgi.py
|
|-WFMBCM_App
|-WFMBCM_db
|-manage.py
|-Dockerfile
|-requirements.txt
|-runWFMBCM.sh
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD WFMBCM /usr/src/app
ADD WFMBCM_App /usr/src/app
ADD WFMBCM_db /usr/src/app
ADD manage.py /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD exec gunicorn wfmbcm.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==2.2.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

runWFMBCM.sh:

```
cd /home/admin/WFMBCM
echo -e "\033[0;34mGo to WFMBCM directory.\n \033[0;37m"
echo -e "\033[0;34mRemove old WFMBCM container\n \033[0;37m"
docker rm -v wfmbcm_container 
echo -e "\033[0;34m\nBuild WFMBCM Docker image.\n \033[0;37m"
sudo docker build -t wfmbcm .
echo -e "\033[0;34m\nRun WFMBCM Docker image.\n \033[0;37m"
sudo docker run --name wfmbcm_container -p 8000:8000 -i -t wfmbcm
echo -e "\033[0;34m\n\nWFMBCM run-script ended!.\n \033[0;37m"
```

When I run runWFMBCM.sh I get the following output:

```
Go to WFMBCM directory.

Remove old WFMBCM container

Error response from daemon: No such container: wfmbcm_container

Build WFMBCM Docker image.

Sending build context to Docker daemon  265.2kB
Step 1/10 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> cc971a68c3e4
Step 2/10 : ADD WFMBCM /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 302346d017e2
Step 3/10 : ADD WFMBCM_App /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18bc8eb69946
Step 4/10 : ADD WFMBCM_db /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0835393b22dc
Step 5/10 : ADD manage.py /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3ef5477e4b26
Step 6/10 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2edb019a8257
Step 7/10 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df3ac922b7a0
Step 8/10 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba6cf54e7dcc
Step 9/10 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94f3f4fb38c0
Step 10/10 : CMD exec gunicorn wfmbcm.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db6cf2149949
Successfully built db6cf2149949
Successfully tagged wfmbcm:latest

Run WFMBCM Docker image.

[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfmbcm'
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfmbcm'
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfmbcm'
[2019-05-26 09:59:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
[2019-05-26 09:59:37 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-05-26 09:59:37 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.


WFMBCM run-script ended!.
```

Why can't it find wfmbcm module? I've been staring crazy and googling without success and looking at different stack overflow questions.

Comment: WFMBCM != wfmbcm. Please, consider following naming convention https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names , don't mix naming style. Keep module and folder names lowercase. Also, you better use `.dockerignore` to exclude files and folders instead of listing allowed folders for copying into image. Copy in one go if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any python module named wfmbcm, so I assume that it's an app in your project.

If you are on a case sensitive file system, then your file layout shows all caps for some folders and that might be (part of) the issue.

Does this project run outside of docker?

If it does, then I think that your best bet is to start the docker container and then manually install the entire app inside the container, updating the dockerfile with the steps as you go.

Every time you test a new change, make sure that you build with the --no-cache option or you may not be testing what you think you are.

Comment: Just noticed this: "gunicorn wfmbcm.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3"

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be either a path or case sensitivity issue.

Comment: You could also try switching the ADD commands to COPY commands

Comment: Thanks found it finally. It was both the paths and the case sensitivity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Changing my DockerFile to this solved my issue:

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD WFMBCM /usr/src/app/WFMBCM
ADD WFMBCM_App /usr/src/app/WFMBCM_App
ADD WFMBCM_db /usr/src/app/WFMBCM_db
ADD manage.py /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD manage.py migrate
CMD exec gunicorn WFMBCM.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 10
```

Comment: There can be only one `CMD` instruction in a Dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy **WFMBCM/WFMBCM/wsgi.py** file in the root of project (so wsgi.py path is WFMBCM/wsgi.py)

and change `CMD exec ...` to this `CMD exec gunicorn wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3`

and you'll be fine to go.